# Finite complement topology

Tags: general-topology

This is one of the past paper problems to my topology finals, but Im not sure how to show this, I would appreciate the help it would really help me revise for my finals.

> **Problem:** Suppose that $X$ is infinite. Then prove that $X$ is connected, compact but not
>   Hausdorff with respect to the finite complement topology $\mathcal{T}_X.$ Where $X$ is the set with the finite complement topology.

Comment: There are three separate claims. Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: All three would be the best, just honestly at this point revising past papers and understand the solutions behind it as my finals are tomorrow, there seems to be no point in trying to understand everything from scratch at this point :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that $X$ is connected, suppose it is not, then $X = X_1 \cup X_2$,  where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are disjoint open sets. By definition of the finite complement topology, $X_1^c = X_2$ and $X_2^c = X_1$, so both are finite hence $X$ being a finite union of finite sets is finite, a contradiction.

To see that $X$ is compact, consider an open cover of $X$. Pick any open set $U$ in the open cover. By definition of finite complement, $U$ leaves out only finitely many points in $X$, and for each such point you can find an open set in the open cover that contains that point. Can you see why $X$ is compact now?

As for Hausdorffness, do you think that *any* two non-empty open sets in this topology can be disjoint? They can't, because then one is contained in the complement of the other, but every open set is infinite, so this would imply that an infinite set is contained in a finite set, a contradiction.

At this point, recall what Hausdorff is : for every pair of unequal points $x \neq y$ there exist disjoint open sets $x \in U_x, y \in U_y$.

So clearly, $X$ is not Hausdorff, since if we pick any two points, say $x,y$, then there are *no disjoint* pair of open sets containing $x$ and $y$ resp., since these open sets are non-empty, and above we explained why they have to intersect.

Comment: Two things, I completely get the argument for compactness. But for connectedness, why is $X$ being a finite union of finite sets being finite a contradiction? Secondly, I am sorry my concepts with Hausdorff seems still weak, could you possibly provide an example using symbols to demonstrate the Non- Hausdorffness? I really appreciate the help.

Comment: For the first, a finite union of finite sets is finite, so if $X$ is a finite union of finite sets then it must be finite, but $X$ is given to be infinite, so there is a problem. For the second, I shall elaborate in the answer.

Comment: O yes my mistake thank you, I did not see that part!!, and yes I would really appreciate that.

Comment: The elaboration is complete.

Comment: So does it mean that connectedness implies non-Hausdorffness, since you have showed that $X_1$ and $X_2 $intersects, and thus cannot be Hausdorff? Which makes me get confused about another question I posted where it says it is not connected and not Hausdorff https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2791037/why-is-x-not-connected-and-not-hausdorff.

Comment: Not really. I shall transfer my attention to that post(I'll comment there to say I've done so). I'll be elaborate there as well. I'd like to have played my part if your exam goes well!

Comment: I would really appreciate the attention on that other post since it has no answers yet, and yes I think would really help me understand some confusions with connectedness and Hausdorffness.